# Select rows so total number not to exceed a certain number

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

I am using SQL Server 2008 and I have a SALES_ORDER table.
Each row of the table is one material. Many rows (materials) can belong to the same ORDER. I want to select the materials of many orders under two conditions:

1. All materials under the same order will be selected (orders will not be split).
2. The total number of selected rows will not exceed a maximum predefined number ROW_MAX.

For example, let's say we have

```
4 materials under order_1
3 materials under order_2
5 materials under order_3
2 materials under order_4
```

and ROW_MAX = 7

the query must return

- all materials of the orders order_1 and order_2 (total 7 materials)
  OR
- all materials of orders order_1 and order_4 (total 6 materials)
  OR
- any other combination of orders so the total number or selected rows does not exceed 7.

Any idea how to do it with SQL script?

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's a bit more tricky than that. I guess the following code answers the requisite:

> *any other combination of orders so the total number or selected rows does not exceed 7*

There's little work to do before you can cross apply.

First we create a data sample in which order1 + order2 is bigger than 7 (so that we can test and doesn't stops looking after order2):

```
-- A sample table in which order1 + order 2 count is bigger than 7
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sample') is not null
    DROP TABLE #sample
CREATE TABLE #sample (
    OrderID     INT,
    OrderDesc   VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO #sample VALUES 
(1, 'Order 1 customer 1'),
(1, 'Order 2 customer 1'),
(1, 'Order 3 customer 1'),
(1, 'Order 4 customer 1'),
(2, 'Order 1 customer 2'),
(2, 'Order 2 customer 2'),
(2, 'Order 3 customer 2'),
(2, 'Order 4 customer 2'),
(2, 'Order 5 customer 2'),
(3, 'Order 1 customer 3'),
(3, 'Order 2 customer 3'),
(4, 'Order 1 customer 4')
```

Then we count the number of row for each order:

```
-- Counting rows for each order
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#samplecount') is not null
   DROP TABLE #samplecount
SELECT OrderID, COUNT(*) as OrderCount
INTO #samplecount
FROM #sample
GROUP BY OrderID
```

We order the orders according that count:

```
--Numbering each row
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#samplecountordered') is not null
   DROP TABLE #samplecountordered
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderCount) AS OrderNumber
INTO #samplecountordered
from #samplecount
```

After that we can use cross apply on that organised repository:

```
select sa.*
from #samplecountordered so cross apply
     (select SUM(OrderCount) as running_count
      from #samplecountordered so2
      where so2.OrderNumber <= so.OrderNumber
      ) so2
INNER JOIN #sample sa
ON sa.OrderID = so.orderID    
where running_count <= 7;
```

This solution requires further testing, but I guess it is the spirit.
I use temporary tables so that it is easier to follow in terms of construction.

Sorry, I used customers instead of material.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a cumulative sum.  In SQL Server 2008, you can do this with `apply`:

```
select so.*
from sales_order so cross apply
     (select count(*) as running_count
      from sales_order so2
      where so2.order_id <= so.order_id
     ) so2
where running_count <= 7;
```

Comment: This query does not work, because I don't add just rows but groups of rows. So I must do cross apply to the group by order_number. but you gave me a direction. thanks

Comment: @user3417479 . . . Your question doesn't mention `order_number` at all.  Use whatever is appropriate for the correlation clause.